# No guardar valores null en un datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de evitar que un datagridview que tengo un formulario de ventana me guarde la fila en blanco que normalmente tiene(Esa ultima que te permite agregar una fila personalizada) la cosa es que cuando lo hago por medio de un foreach me presenta este mensaje:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

En lo que me estuve fijando, el error lo da al llegar a la casilla vacía.

No solo para ese proceso, casi todo lo que intento hacer en ese datagridview que tenga que ver con sacar algo de entre los datos que estén en el hacia cualquier parte del programa me da ese error.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFactura.Rows)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["DetalleFac"].Value.ToString()))//aquí da error
            {
                Double Vimpuesto = 0;
                Vimpuesto += ((Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Precio"].Value)) / (1 + Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["TaxFac"].Value)) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["TaxFac"].Value));
                string sqlMovimiento = "insert into Movimiento (Invoice, Fecha, cliente, Item, Descripcion, impuesto, Vimpuesto, valor, origen, Entrada, salida) values ('" + txtCodigoFac.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm") + "','" + txtCodigo.Text + "','" + row.Cells["Codigo"].Value + "','" + row.Cells["DetalleFac"].Value + "','" + row.Cells["TaxFac"].Value + "','" + Vimpuesto + "','" + row.Cells["Precio"].Value + "','Venta','0','" + row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value + "')";
                if (funcion.GuardarBruto(sqlMovimiento))
                {
                    funcion.CargarData(dgvArticulos, sqlstr);
                }
            }
        }
```

Este es mi código por si algo me falta, que en realidad no creo, pero aun así lo pongo.

Answer (score 1):

El error en tu código se produce al hacer un **.ToString()** de un valor nulo.

Reemplazalo por el siguiente:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFactura.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["detalleFac"].Value != null && row.Cells["detalleFac"].Value.ToString() != String.Empty)
            {
                Double Vimpuesto = 0;
                Vimpuesto += ((Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Precio"].Value)) / (1 + Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["TaxFac"].Value)) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["TaxFac"].Value));
                string sqlMovimiento = "insert into Movimiento (Invoice, Fecha, cliente, Item, Descripcion, impuesto, Vimpuesto, valor, origen, Entrada, salida) values ('" + txtCodigoFac.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm") + "','" + txtCodigo.Text + "','" + row.Cells["Codigo"].Value + "','" + row.Cells["DetalleFac"].Value + "','" + row.Cells["TaxFac"].Value + "','" + Vimpuesto + "','" + row.Cells["Precio"].Value + "','Venta','0','" + row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value + "')";
                if (funcion.GuardarBruto(sqlMovimiento))
                {
                    funcion.CargarData(dgvArticulos, sqlstr);
                }
            }
        }
```

Saludos.